# Возможность запрета скачивания меди файлов в telegram

Tags: telegram

Есть ли возможность запрета на скачивание медиа файлов в групповом чате телеги?

Comment: Это технически невозможно. Кроме как удалить все файлы из чата.

Comment: @andreymal понял, спасибо.